# 2 different array with different values

Tags: php, arrays

My question may sound abit silly, but I know it is possible to do. I'm actually trying to make the array from mysql to be different from the array I have `shuffle` it already. I want to maintain the array keys, just the value in different order.

Here is the example,

**Array from MYSQL:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
)
```

**Array after `shuffle`:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 6
)
```

If you notice, `MYSQL array` key 3 has the same value as `shuffle array`, I want it to be different. How can I do so?

**Here is my code:**

```
function get_random_elements($array) {
    $ori_array = $array;

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($ori_array);
    echo "</pre>";

    shuffle($array);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";

    for($x=0; $x<count($array); $x++) {
        if ($array[$x] == $ori_array[$x])
        {
            $dupliarray[] = "Array value: ".$array[$x]." Key :".$x;
            unset($array[$x]);
        }

    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($dupliarray);
    echo "</pre>";

}

$mysql_array = array(0=>'1',1=>'2',2=>'3',3=>'4',4=>'5',5=>'6',6=>'7',7=>'8');

get_random_elements($mysql_array);
```

Comment: call `get_random_elements` function recursively until(which is count($dupliarray) is 0) you get totally different array from the original array.

Comment: @Naga Hmm... true, but how do I call recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution can be to shuffle array until it became totally differ from source array:

```
$sourceArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
$shuffledArray = $sourceArray; //because function shuffle will change passed array

shuffle($shuffledArray);    
while (count(array_intersect_assoc($sourceArray, $shuffledArray))) {
    shuffle($shuffledArray);
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($sourceArray, $shuffledArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this variant: [Code in sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8fa9f485b7e2f5292d1b098207015a47c0602389)

```
$startArray = [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 4,
    4 => 5,
    5 => 6,
    6 => 7,
    ];

function getShuffledArray($startArray) {

    $shuffledArray = [];

    // save value of last element for situation when we have last 2 elements of start array and one of them - last
    $lastElement = end($startArray);

    while (count($startArray)) {
        $candidateIndex = array_rand($startArray);
        if ($candidateIndex == count($shuffledArray)) {
            while ($candidateIndex == count($shuffledArray)) {
                $candidateIndex = array_rand($startArray);
            }
        }
        $shuffledArray[] = $startArray[$candidateIndex];
        unset($startArray[$candidateIndex]);

        // shuffle last two elements when one of them last (in start array)
        if (count($startArray) == 2 && end($startArray) == $lastElement) {
            $shuffledArray[] = end($startArray);
            $shuffledArray[] = reset($startArray);
            $startArray = [];
        }
    }

    return $shuffledArray;
}

$shuffledArray = getShuffledArray($startArray);
print_r ($shuffledArray);
```